# what is best option for creating log message buffer

Tags: java, rest, logging

I am working on a web application which needs to be deployed to cloud. There is a cloud service which can store log messages for applications securely. This is exposed by cloud using REST API which can take up to max 25 log messages in json format. we are currently using log4j(open for any other too) to log in to file. Now, we need to transition our application to move from file based logging to using cloud REST API.

I am considering that it would be expensive to make REST API call for every log message and slow down the application.

in this context, I am considering writing a custom appender which can write to a buffer. buffer can be in-memory or persistent buffer which will be read and emptied periodically by a separate thread or process by sending 25 messages in bunch to cloud REST API.

option 1:

using in-memory buffer
my custom appender would write message to in memory list and keep filling it.
There woudl be a daemon thread which will keep removing 25 messages at a time from the buffer and write to cloud using REST API. There is a downside to this approach that in event of application/server/node crashing.. we lose critical log message which can lead to diagnostic of why crash occurred.I am not sure if this is right way of thinking.

option 2:

using persistent buffer database/message queue:

appender can log message to database table temporarily or post to message queue which will be processed by separate long running job to pick up messages from db or queue and post it to cloud using REST API.

please guide which option looks best.

Comment: You can log each log to a file and then use inmemory to append 25 logs and send it to cloud.

Comment: why do you think option 1 has a future? You've already mentioned that an application crash will lose your logs ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of build in appender in log4j : https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html and if you use a dedicated service in a cloud, they may give a specific appender.
If it's in your environment, maybe try a stack like [ELK](https://www.elastic.co/downloads) with log4j rollingfile apender, with that technique you'll not lose log entries.